# C# - Speeding up a List comparison that uses nested for-loops

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, object, for-loop

I am currently developing a test program that makes sure that holes on a motherboard aren't too close to each other or that they aren't overlapping.

In order to do this, I am keeping all of the holes' X, Y coordinates and radii in objects called holeInfo's and the objects inside the list holeInfoList.

I am currently using a nested for loop to go through all of the holes and a basic mathematical formula to check the distance between the holes.

Here is the function I use:

```
public void checkHoleConditions()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < holeInfoList.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        errorType = new List<string>();

        for (int j = i + 1; j < holeInfoList.Count; j++)
        {
            holeMinSpaceFailed = false;

            if (failsHoleConditions(holeInfoList[i], holeInfoList[j])) 
            {
                if (holeMinSpaceFailed)
                {
                    errorType.Add("X: " + holeInfoList[j].holeXCoordinate + " Y: " + holeInfoList[j].holeYCoordinate + "R: " + holeInfoList[j].holeDiameter + " too close.");
                }
                else
                {
                    errorType.Add("X: " + holeInfoList[j].holeXCoordinate + " Y: " + holeInfoList[j].holeYCoordinate + "R: " + holeInfoList[j].holeDiameter + " overlap.");
                }

                invalidHole = new InvalidHole(holeInfoList[i], errorType);
                invalidHoleList.Add(invalidHole);
                Console.WriteLine("Hole Error Detected");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hole Check Successful");
            }
        }
    }
}

public bool failsHoleConditions(HoleInfo holeOne, HoleInfo holeTwo)
    {
        float holeOneXCoordinate = holeOne.holeXCoordinate;
        float holeOneYCoordinate = holeOne.holeYCoordinate;
        float holeOneRadius = holeOne.holeDiameter / 2;

        float holeTwoXCoordinate = holeTwo.holeXCoordinate;
        float holeTwoYCoordinate = holeTwo.holeYCoordinate;
        float holeTwoRadius = holeTwo.holeDiameter / 2;

        float holeXDifferenceSquared = (float)Math.Pow((holeOneXCoordinate - holeTwoXCoordinate), 2);
        float holeYDifferenceSquared = (float)Math.Pow((holeOneYCoordinate - holeTwoYCoordinate), 2);
        float distanceBetweenCenters = (float)Math.Sqrt(holeXDifferenceSquared + holeYDifferenceSquared);

        float distanceBetweenHoles = distanceBetweenCenters - (holeOneRadius + holeTwoRadius);

        if (distanceBetweenHoles <= 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (distanceBetweenHoles <= minimumSpace)
        {
            holeMinSpaceFailed = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Currently, my program does the test in about 2.5 minutes for 254 list objects. Considering that this is a test program, 2.5 minutes for only 254 holes is a long time.

What are some of the algorithms that I can implement to make the test run faster?

Comment: Seems like this is more suited to code review?

Comment: Parallelize your code (Parallel.For for example) and maybe try stringbuilder instead of string, not sure what would be faster in that case.

Comment: @VladimirArustamian I'm not sure where stringbuilder would help here? Also, you have to be careful running nested loops in parallel.

Comment: You'll currently be writing out thousands of lines to the console. The console  *can* be a bottleneck in some cases. Have you tried removing that? Next, have you profiled the code to work out where it's slow? What does `failsHoleConditions` do?

Comment: @JonSkeet failsHoleCondition simply takes the distance between the centers using some basic mathematical formulas and runs them against an if-else if statement. I can post the code as well if you'd like. As for the console, I started writing onto the console later on to see if the program was actually working still after I saw that the process was taking a lot of time.

Comment: What is this? holeMinSpaceFailed = false;  Clearly the failsHoleConditions is what is taking time.  Remove that call and see how long it takes.

Comment: Would strongly recommend profiling the code as @JonSkeet suggests to get a clearer picture of the slow areas, it often reveals surprises. I tripped myself up in the past with console output performance (may not be the case for you).

Comment: Another optimization in your distance computation would be to remove the 'Math.Sqrt' call cause the square root function is pretty slow. Then you would just compare with the square of the minimum space which you could only calculate once before the loop.

Comment: I ran this exact code, but for 10000 randomly generated holes. Execution time was around 5-6 seconds. The only way it could've taken 2.5 minutes is if `holeInfoList` is a custom type that computes `pi` to 800000 decimal places each time you access an element.

Comment: @AlexanderMP can you share the exact complete code you used so that I could maybe see any differences?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7x1umfZW
I just filled in the missing pieces with some stubs, just to get it working. I also commented out the output, since at 10000 holes it took ages to output all of that. Worked fast with output for 255 holes however.

Comment: @JonSkeet The problem was because of Console.WriteLine("Hole Check Successful");

After removing the line, the runtime went from an average to 2.5 minutes to almost none. Apparently it actually was bottlenecking the entire program.

Comment: @BerkeJimmyBakkaloğlu   You had stated you had the problem before the Console.WriteLine.   I have a solution posted that runs 1 million is less then 300 milliseconds.

Comment: @Paparazzi I swear it did take a lot of time before as well, but after the suggestions I thought I'd try it again. So I did and it worked out.

Comment: @BerkeJimmyBakkaloğlu Even if you do not accept my answer you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

holeMinSpaceFailed will never be true if failsHoleConditions is true
don't pass around logic like that

`x * x` is faster then `Math.Pow`

No need to take Sqrt - just square minimumSpace

Something like this. **Runs 1 million 300 milliseconds.** Something is wrong for your code to take minutes.

```
static byte HoleTooClose(HoleInfo x, HoleInfo y, float minDistance)
{
    float holeSize = (x.Diameter + y.Diameter) / 2;
    float deltaX = y.X - x.X;
    float deltaY = y.Y - x.Y;

    float distanceSquared = deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY - holeSize * holeSize;

    if (distanceSquared <= 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    float minDistanceSquared = minDistance * minDistance;
    if (distanceSquared <= minDistanceSquared)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 2;
}

internal struct HoleInfo
{
    public float Diameter { get; internal set; }
    public float X { get; internal set; }
    public float Y { get; internal set; }
    public HoleInfo (float x, float y, float diameter)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Diameter = diameter;
    }
}


static bool DistanceTooClose(System.Windows.Point x, System.Windows.Point y, Double minDistance)
{
    double deltaX = Math.Abs(y.X - x.X);
    double deltaY = Math.Abs(y.Y - x.Y);
    double distanceSquared = deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY;
    //double distance = Math.Sqrt(distanceSquared);
    Double minDistanceSquared = minDistance * minDistance;
    return (distanceSquared <= minDistanceSquared);
}
```

Comment: Fixed the logic issue. Also if I just square minimumSpace, wouldn't it cause some problems when calculating distanceBetweenHoles since I'm subtracting the radii from it to check if it's less than zero?

Comment: subtract the radi from the x and y distance before squaring them. Why are you dividing the radius by two at the beginning?

Comment: @BoeseB The variables getting divided are actually diameters, I recently found out about the type of input but never got around to changing the names. I'll do that now.

Comment: @BerkeJimmyBakkaloğlu see this [gist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45078206/4369295) for the changes suggested in this answer and the comments

Comment: @BerkeJimmyBakkaloğlu [Sorry messed up the link here is the right one](https://gist.github.com/BoeseB/e8ecf8605c9270e9bff612bce4cf406a)

Comment: @BoeseB I don't think the way you subtract the radius is correct.

Comment: @Paparazzi yeah you are right, corrected the way how i subtract them

Answer (score 3):

An inspiration for this solution is physics engines, and the optimizations there that take care of collision detection.

I don't claim to know entirely how it works, and for better solutions you should try researching ODE or Bullet Dynamics for this.

Basically the solution is to separate objects (holes) into islands, and only compare each object's position to objects in the same island. If you can't come up with a way to properly separate islands, you could just do this:

Suppose we have 125 objects on a square field, 5 by 5. You can divide it into 25 primary square islands, and then 8 intersection islands (long islands, along the edges of the primary islands. The smallest side of these islands should be the minimum distance you want to compute). Islands can overlap. You have to parse the whole list once to make this split. Which means that so far we loop through 125 items total - `O(n)`.

Next, for each island (33 total, `O(n^(2/3))`, find objects that are closer than they have to be, by using those same nested loops. Total complexity of each island is `O((n / n^(2/3))^2)` = `O(n^(2/3))`. Times the number of islands, we get total complexity for this algorithm = `O(n^(4/3))`, which is smaller than `O(n^2)` that was originally presented.

Hope this makes sense. I can write a Python demo if you want. It's just that it would be quite a lot of code.

**Edit:**
Or you could just use a 2D physics engine and plot the objects as circles with a diameter equal to the minimum distance between holes and then let it detect the collisions. Or take the relevant code from there (if license permits), since the entire physics engine is a bit overkill for the task.
https://github.com/VelcroPhysics/VelcroPhysics

**Edit 2:**

> 254 list objects

I thought you were parsing 254 different boards. This solution I highlighted would make sense only in huge computational loads.

Comment: I don't think you need this for 254 holes.  I wrote a test case that does 1 million in under 1 second.

Comment: You do need it for larger numbers however. See my "Edit 2".

Answer (score 0):

If you need to test all against all, one optimization can be to put them in a nxn matrix, instead of a list. Then, execute the validation on parallel. The bigger the matrix and the more cores you have the better. The parallel can also be executed on the list, but I'm not 100% sure if .Net will determine to wait for each thread to end, as the algorithm is sequential.

If your method uses euclidean distance, you can try to order the list first, based on this distance. sqr(x)+sqr(y) with respect to 0 can be a score to sort first. I think .Net can handle this sorting easily. Later, just run your algorithm till the first allowed circuit. Then, you know the rest must be accepted, so you will only execute on the first elements of the list